# Android Studio: Buttons with drawable selector displaying background wrong when applied programmatically

Tags: android, selector

Im trying to change the background of some buttons programmatically with a selector. 
I have two different selectors

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/palette.greyscale.lightgrey" android:state_pressed="false"></item>
<item android:drawable="@color/palette.blue.mid" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
```

and

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/palette.greyscale.lightgrey" android:state_pressed="false"></item>
<item android:drawable="@color/palette.orange.mid" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
```

---

which get applied programmatically depending on a boolean:

```
void setUI() {
    int primary;
    Drawable btn_color;
    if (((App) getActivity().getApplication()).isGender_isMale()) {
        primary = getResources().getColor(R.color.palette_blue_mid);
        btn_color = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_blue);
    }
    else {
        primary = getResources().getColor(R.color.palette_orange_mid);
        btn_color = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_orange);
    }
btn_speichern.setBackground(btn_color);
btn_teilen.setBackground(btn_color);
btn_offnen.setBackground(btn_color);
}
```

---

Here is one button from the fragment xml:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_speichern"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
        android:text="Speichern"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

When pressing one button another button also triggers the selector.

When changing the background in the fragment xml it works fine.
I also tried to remove `android:background="@drawable/button_blue"` which refers to one of the drawables ressource file, but with no sucess.

I think you can get a better picture of what my issue is by taking a look at this:
https://youtu.be/y2xKHz3bgfs

**EDIT:**
**It seems like the selector always selects the button that is pressed and the next button with the same drawable background.**

Answer (score 0):

If you've got two distinct buttons you could attach onClickListeners to each and then have the onClick call send a message to your main activity indicating that the button was pressed

Comment: That's not really what I was asking. I have problems with the selectors as you can see in the video.

Comment: .getColor is deprecated kindly use ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.my_color)

Comment: For Drawable

ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.back_arrow)
For Color

 ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.red)